# How to read and untar tar.gz files in IPython

Tags: python

I tried

```
%%sh
tar xvf filename.tar.gz
```

but it didn't work.
How to read tar.gz files in IPython.

Comment: It didn't work? What didn't work? What did you expect it to do? What did it do instead?

Comment: Try this first "gzip -d filename.tar.gz" will uncompress the file and rename it to "filename.tar"

Comment: Was anything printed out after you've executed the command?

Comment: You cannot - please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you want to do that with Python (and specially with IPython), but it's ok...

For put a command into the system with Python i would use subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call
# The first param must be the command, and then the options,
# Something like 
call(["tar", "-xzf", "filename.tar.gz"])
```

And that must work not only on Ipython, but in every Python program.